# Wheatstone bridge

Tags: wheatstone-bridge

I need help with solving the following Wheatstone bridge circuit.

I don't know the value of the resistances nor the capacitor.
Where or how do I get started to calculate them?

The variable resistance will be connected to a pair of electrodes.

[image]

Comment: Given the C is across a DC reference, just assume it is large (and state that assumption) and analyse the circuit without it.

Answer (score 4):

- The LM431 provides a stable voltage reference for the bridge.
- C<sub>d</sub> filters out any noise from the LM431. It does not affect the bridge and may be ignored during analysis.

The rest of the problem can be solved as shown in thousands of online articles.

Answer (score 2):

The capacitor does not affect a DC analysis. Read the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm431.pdf) for the LM431 and choose a capacitor value that guarantees stability (avoid the 'tunnel of death' values).

[image]

You will pick a value for Ra that guarantees the bridge gets full current with minimum value for the sensor and minimum value for the 3.3V supply, plus the current the LM431 needs to operate (read the datasheet, again, about 1mA).

Pick R2/R4 to balance the bridge at the desired sensor value. The absolute value of R2 or R4 is picked based on how much current you want to pass through the passive side of the bridge and how much output impedance you can tolerate.

Pick R1 depending on how much current you can put through the sensor and if that is not a limitation then a reasonable choice might be the geometric mean of the sensor value in the useful range.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is, pick the three bridge resistors to be one half the expected resistance range of the variable.

That gives you a zero differential output when the variable is at the midpoint.

This does not apply (exactly) if the sensor resistance is non-linear. Then you have to decide on what value of sensor needs the most sensitivity.

A slightly less-tailored approach is to pick R1 as before, and R2 and R3 are equal-valued for some convenient value.